# Cannot connect to document db when username and password are passed as arguments

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have a documentdb cluster, I m unable to connect to documentDB when I pass username and password args at once

`mongo --host <myDocDbHost>:27017 --username admin --password <myPassword>`
I get following error

```
connecting to: mongodb://< myDocDbHost>:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2021-10-26T21:09:17.228+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:356:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Where as when I try
`mongo --host <myDocDbHost>:27017 --username admin` and enter password in next prompt where it asks for Password I m able to connect. I verified that I m using the correct password in both cases. I had same issue when I tried to connect directly from EC2 instance in same VPC as documentDB and through ssh tunneling as well. Can someone help me connect to db by passing both username and password args at once

Comment: 1. `mongo` is the shell not db, 2. Does you password have special symbols?

Comment: try this : mongo --host HOST  --port PORT -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470 The (default) Authentication database depends on the connection string.

Comment: Found the issue its due to special chars in password. I m able to login now. I updated password to not have any special chars thanks all